# How can I configure NHibernate with classes from child project into the parent project in C#?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reference, assemblies, configure

I have a parent project A and all my classes are located in my child project B. I need to get the assemblies of all these classes. I tried to use:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

but it returns only the assemblies from the parent project A.

Is there a way I can access to the assemblies of Project B without making any references from Project A to Project B?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both assemblies are in the bin directory, you could try this:

```
var assemblies =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "*.dll")
        .Select(Assembly.Load);
```

Comment: I found an alternative to this. I needed this before only for the configuration of NHibernate via StructureMap. Now, instead of building the configuration from the parent project, I have set a static NHibernate configuration and I initialize it from the child. That way I don't have any reference from Project A to Project B.

Thank you for your help.
Hope this helps.